# What are Search Targets and Search Query Input in seomatic?

Tags: plugin-seomatic

I am not sure this is the right place to ask this question but I really need to know it, but I couldn't ask it on the plugin's Github as this is not an issue. I am new on Craft CMS and my client need SEOmatic installed on it. I have configured everything but I couldn't understand the need of `Search Targets and Search Query Input` in [Site Meta Section](https://github.com/nystudio107/seomatic/wiki/03a.-Configuring-SEO-Site-Meta). It would be very helpful if someone helps me out for this with some real-life examples.

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with Google Structured Data and how your site appears in search results. If you use these fields, your site will show a custom search box in Google Search results, like this:

[image]

Basically, the `Search Target` is a URL where you'd want any search queries to get directed to. So in the example above for Pinterest and a custom search for "Pizza", the `Search Target` might be:

```
pinterest.com/search?q={search_term_string}
```

The `Search Query Input` basically just tells Google what the placeholder is that you used in the `Search Target`. So in our example it would be:

```
search_term_string
```

I'd recommend reading [this 
page](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitelinks-searchbox) from the Google Search docs in order to better understand what `Search Targets` and the `Search Query Input` are.